# Cálculo em SELECT Oracle

Tags: oracle, pl-sql

Preciso fazer o calculo entre valores que estão armazenados no meu BD, esses valores estão assinalados com o sinal de + e - em suas respectivas tabelas.
Gostaria de saber se existe alguma forma de fazer com que através de um único comando SQL eu faça essas conta:

- Somar todos os valores que possuem o sinal de +;
- Somar todos os valores que possuem o sinal de -;
- Diminuir o resultado de um pelo outro;

O comando SQL que fiz até agora é:

```
select sum(valeve) as valor from R046VER                                
            where numemp = 404 and numcad = 4170 and codcal = 1136 and              
            codeve in (select codeve from R008INC where incfgm in('+', '-') and codtab = 1) and         
            tabeve = 1 and codeve not in(select codeve from R008EVC where codtab = 1            
            and crteve in('31B','31C','31E','31F','31G','31H','31I','31J','31M','39Z','39Z','39Z','49Z','50A','50F'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Use o [decode](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions040.htm) e multiplique pelo valor

```
select sum(decode(incfgm,'+',1,'-',-1,0)*valeve) as valor 
from R046VER  
where numemp = 404 
and numcad = 4170 
and codcal = 1136 
and codeve in (select codeve 
               from R008INC 
               where incfgm in('+', '-') 
               and codtab = 1) 
and tabeve = 1 
and codeve not in(select codeve 
                  from R008EVC where codtab = 1            
                  and crteve in ('31B','31C','31E','31F',
                                 '31G','31H','31I','31J',
                                 '31M','39Z','39Z','39Z',
                                 '49Z','50A','50F'))
```

Comment: E o perguntador some.

Comment: Dependendo da origem dos dados e de como foram tratados é possível ser injetada uma expressão maliciosa para ser processada com decode.

Comment: Neste caso não creio pois os campos deveriam ter constraints, mas qualquer entrada precisa ser tratada, uma outra solução aqui é ter um campo calculado na tabela algo como "valeve_s" que já estaria sinalizado.